# FCM Push Notification not received after some time or reboot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a little problem here that I, unfortunately, I currently can't really solve it by myself, so asking for help here.

I am trying to build push notifications in my app and I am using FCM.
For this whole process I use:

- Android application with firebase
- PHP Script to send FCM Push Notifications
- MySQL DB to store tokens.

It works the following way: Each time a new token is generated, I send this token to my MySQL db where it is then stored. A PHP script that I have reads db for all tokens that it can find and sends push notification to all the devices.

I have watched many youtube videos and read multiple articles on how to do that and I managed to get it working, however, it is quite unstable and I can't get it to work persistently.

Here are some scenarios where it doesn't work for unknown to me reason.

Case 1:

- Day 1:
  I just installed application, launched it and then put it in background. Sent Push and received it successfully. In 3-4 hours I send notification again and successfully receive it.
- Day 2: Right after Day 1, at 1 AM in the morning of Day 2 I sent notification again and it was never received. I went to bed and in the morning the message was never received still so I tried to send message again and my php script says that message was received (as per Firebase console response), but the notification is never shown.

-- Note: I have also implemented a method inside "onMessageReceived()" to save the message to MySQL so that I can personally monitor if the device at least received the message to better understand how it works, but the device never even received it.

Case 2:

- Day 1: Installed application. Launched it, closed it and sent Push. Successfully received.
  In 1 hour, I reboot my phone. 20 mins later I tried sending Push but I never received it. I tried launching application and putting it in background, yet I still received nothing.
  I tried sending some Notifications not with PHP script, but with FCM Console, but still nothing.
  Only after 10 minutes I received Notifications that I send some time ago, yet I tried sending notifications with my PHP script and it still didn't work and only after few more minutes I could send notifications with my PHP again.

The behavior that I described above is simply very chaotic to my understanding. I don't follow any logic whatsoever.

My Code:

PHP Script:

```
<?php 

function send_notification ($tokens, $data, $priority)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
        'delay_while_idle' => false,
        'android' => $priority,
        'data' => $data,
        'registration_ids' => $tokens
    );

    //var_dump($fields);

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key = KJAdkashdkhaiiwueyIhAXZ.....',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   
   print($ch);
   print("<br>");
   print("<br>");
   print($result);
   print("<br>");
   print("<br>");
   print(json_encode($fields));
   print("<br>");
   print("<br>");
   
   if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}

$conn = mysqli_connect('ip_address', 'username', "password", 'mydatabasename');

$sql = "SELECT TOKEN FROM users";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$tokens = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tokens[] = $row["TOKEN"];
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);

$data = array(
    'title' => 'This is title of the message',
    'body' => 'This is body of the message',
    'contents' => 'Simple contents of the message'
    );

$android = array(
    'priority' => 'high'
);

$message_status = send_notification($tokens, $data, $android);
echo $message_status;
```

Android:

MyFirebaseMessagingService

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

        // Save received message to MySQL
        HUC.success()

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: ${remoteMessage.data}")
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        remoteMessage.notification?.let {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: ${it.body}")
        }

        // Send notification containing the body of data payload
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.data["body"].toString())
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    // [START on_new_token]
    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: $token")
        
        // Saving my registration token to MySQL
        sendRegistrationToServer(token)
    }
    // [END on_new_token]

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private fun sendRegistrationToServer(token: String?) {
        CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
            // HttpURLConnection function to save token to MySQL
            val response = HUC.saveToken(token)
            withContext(Main){
                Log.d(TAG, "Server response: $response")
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private fun sendNotification(messageBody: String) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
        )

        val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.fcm_message))
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build())
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService"
    }
}
```

Please help me understand here. Maybe I am doing something wrong or perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: Hey @Rey-0, regarding your case 1, did you restart the application between your "Day 1" and "Day 2" tests? It may be the case that data notifications are not delivered properly if the app have been killed by android (which may happen when leaving it in background so long). Based on your `onMessageRetrieved` it seems you're relying on data notifications, if it works for your use case it may be worth to look into Notification Messages instead [https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications]

Comment: @Marino Hello. No, I haven't restarted the phone between Day 1 and Day 2. About Notification Message - From what I have here on stackoverflow It seemed to me that in order for my application to receive Push Notifications even if it's in the background, I should be using Data Messages, since when Data Messages received "onMessageReceived" is called even if app is killed or in background. Maybe I misunderstood something, so please, correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: I meant restarting the app, which should be enough :) Actually, staying at the docs (linked above) both `Notification Messages` and `Data Notifications` will be received when in background. The difference is that for `Data` ones only a part of them is delivered to the notification tray when in background, as the data payload will only be handled when the user taps on the notification. `Messages notifications` are automatically handled by FCM instead, so giving them a shot may help excluding some of the pieces and start figuring out where the issue lives :)

Comment: @Marino I see. I will go through that documentation again more thoroughly and hopefully will be able to figure this out. Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact, everything started working properly when I hard reset my phone which leads me to believe that it was internal phone problem rather than my implementation.